# Filename validation upload in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, button, upload

I want to restrict the user to upload a filename that contain letters, special characters and space.

I would like to only allow numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and with a maximum of 11 numbers.

Example: 54874563101.png

An upload button solution in javascript will be perfect

Can someone help? Thank you

```html
<button type="button" onclick="upload()" value="upload"  id="buttonUpload">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Like an Amazon password / filename?

Comment: ? No. Just a filename restriction for letters and special characters and only allow  user to upload a file that contain only numbers as filename.

Comment: Like a regex `[0-9]+` ?

Comment: yes like a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the file name length and then use regex to ensure only digits are provided within the name.

```js
$("#file").on("change", function() {
    const rawFileName = $("#file").val().split('\\').pop().split(".");
    const fileName = rawFileName[0];
    const fileExtension = rawFileName[1];

    // Validate file extension.
    if (fileExtension !== "png") {
        alert("Only .png files are allowed!");
        return;
    }

    // Validate file name.
    if (fileName.length > 11) {
        alert("File name must be 11 or less characters!");
        return;
    }

    if (!(/^\d+$/.test(fileName))) {
        alert("Only digits are allowed in the file name!");
        return;
    }

    // Validate file size.
    const fileSize = $("#file")[0].files[0].size;

    if ((fileSize < 40000) || (fileSize > 100000)) {
        alert("File size must be between 40kb and 100kb!");
        return;
    }

    // Validated.
    alert("File name valid!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/png" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Validating File Name

To fetch the file name using jQuery, we can use:

```js
const fileName = $("#file").val();
```

However this will output a fill relative path along with the file extension, therefore we can further separate the file name and extension.

```js
const rawFileName = $("#file").val().split('\\').pop().split(".");
const fileName = rawFileName[0];
const fileExtension = rawFileName[1];
```

We can then match the file name to determine it only contains digits using the regex expression `/^\d+$/`:

- `^` Assets position at the start
- `\d` Matches digit characters from [0-9]
- `+` Matches the previous token until the end of the string
- `$` Assets position to the end

#### Validating File Size

To fetch the size of a file in jQuery:

```js
const fileSize = $("#file")[0].files[0].size;
```

This returns an `int` value containing the size in bytes of the first file that is uploaded. *(in this form, only single-file uploads are allowed so it is stored under `files[0]`)*

```js
if ((fileSize < 40000) || (fileSize > 100000))
```

`40000` bytes equate to 40kb, and `100000` bytes is 100kb.

#### File Upload Extension Restriction

To restrict the file uploader to only accept specific file extensions, the `accept` property can be added to the `input` element.

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/png" />
```

The `image/png` value only allows files with the `.png` extension, see [unique file type specifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#unique_file_type_specifiers) for more information.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '^'   here :   if (!(^\d+$/.test(fileName)))

Comment: Updated, I have also included jQuery though if you need a solution without it, let me know and I can provide an alternative.

Comment: What about the file extension? You aren't accounting for that

Comment: I check now :) Thank you

Comment: for the file extension is png if possible ? and if it's not too much... file size minimum 40kb and max 100 kb

Comment: Do you mean restricting it only to `.png` files?

Comment: yes please only to .png

Comment: @Michael777 I have updated the answer to only allow `.png` extensions and a file size between 40kb - 100kb.

Comment: Great! just a question please: is it possible to restrict directly on the input in the first place instead of first upload and then submit?

Comment: For the file extension? The above example is doing this already, the `accept="image/png"` property only allows selection of `.png` files.

Comment: I mean for all the restriction. User upload and immediately alert popup show up instead of upload first and then press submit to see the alert. Yes like accept="image/png" but also for the rest of the restriction: size and regex.

Comment: Yes of course, you can simply run the validation when the file is uploaded rather than when the submit button is pressed using the `"change"` event for the file element. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Great it's nearly working: Alert are showing but the file name is accepted. Maybe something to do with "return;" to reject it ?? maybe instead of "return;"  we can try with:  this.value = null;..... It's perfect thank you very much!!!! 5 STARS :) iI upvoted "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."